# I am getting below error while running simple struts 2 application-

Tags: struts2

Unable to load configuration. - action -

> file:/D:/DATA/STUDY/anup/Struts2Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/FirstStrutsApplication/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:6:55
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: Action class
>   [com.javatpoint.Product] not found - action -
>   file:/D:/DATA/STUDY/anup/Struts2Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/FirstStrutsApplication/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:6:55
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:409)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:354)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:468)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">; 
<struts> 
  <package name="default" extends="struts-default"> 
    <action name="getTutorial" class="com.anup.work.TutorialAction" method="execute"> 
      <result name="success">/success.jsp</result> 
    </action> 
  </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: can you at least explain what are you working on ?

Comment: Looks like invalid `struts.xml` to me. Run it though a validator. Maybe post some more detail or this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Actually i am new to struts and i have created a simple application using struts. But while running application i am getting error as unable to load struts.xml. So could you please let me know what need to be done in order to run the application??? I have included all the libs in build path

Comment: Show your `struts.xml` file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    
    
     <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
     
      <action name="getTutorial" 
            class="com.anup.work.TutorialAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
      </action>
      
      </package>
      
     

</struts>

Answer (score 0):

The answer states explicitly what the problem is:

```
Action class [com.javatpoint.Product] not found
```

Your action class is not being deployed, or simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your .class file is not being created. right click on your project, go to properties. select java compiler and check the settings(uncheck the Enable check-box).